ECS task creating non ephemeral port mapping on ALB
I got a setup where my ECS service is using a target group. The same target group is also used by an ALB.  The ECS task definition is configured to use Bridge networkmode. When the ecs service starts on a day, it would register a target (ec2 instance) to the target group but the port that gets assigned to the registered target is a NON ephemeral port range. Eg:10240, 10241, … etc.
In the ECS task definition the port mapping is 0:80.
What could be the reason why the ephemeral port range(>32,000) is not used for the registered target?
Verified all cloudformation settings and read through many AWS documentation. I would expect that the port that get assigned automatically to the host is in the ephemeral port range.
